# How to change the appeareance of bibliography item labels in amsrefs?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, bold, oldstylenums, amsrefs

Assume that I'd like to set the item labels in the "references" list in amsrefs in, say, boldface (or in lining numbers - I have oldstyle numbers set throughout the document).  I can do it in citations in the text (obtained through `\cite`) by means of redefining `\citeform`; but how to do it for the references list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the labels by redefining `\BibLabel`; for reference, here's the original definition (as given in `amsref.sty`):

```
\newcommand{\BibLabel}{%
    \hfill
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}%
    [\thebib]%
}
```

In the following example I patched `\BibLabel` with the help of `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox`package using an auxiliary command (`\biblistlabelfont`) so that the labels will appear using boldfaced  oldstyle numerals:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\biblistlabelfont}{%
    \normalfont
    \bfseries\footnotesize
}

\patchcmd{\BibLabel}{\thebib}{\biblistlabelfont\oldstylenums{\thebib}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{lamport}
\cite{knuth}
\cite{patashnik}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{knuth}{book}{
      author={Knuth, Donald~E.},
      title={{TeX} and {M}etafont, {N}ew {D}irections in {T}ypesetting},
     publisher={American Mathematical Society and Digital Press},
     address={Stanford},
     date={1979},
}

\bib{lamport}{book}{
      author={Lamport, Leslie},
      title={{LaTeX}: {A} {D}ocument {P}reparation {S}ystem},
      edition={Second},
      publisher={Addison-Wesley},
      address={Reading, Massachusetts},
     date={1994},
}

\bib{patashnik}{misc}{
      author={Patashnik, Oren},
      title={{BibTeX}ing. {D}ocumentation for {G}eneral {BibTeX} {U}sers},
      how={Electronic document accompanying BibTeX distribution},
      date={1988},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using `\patchcmd` because there might be other packages trying to redefine `\BibLabel`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: yes, that's a good point. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: thanks a lot.  Already knowing a bit about `amsrefs`, I did not expect an "easy" way;).

Comment: @StephanLehmke: good point indeed, though in my case I know exactly what packages I load and therefore I could do without it.