# How to mark different bibliographies with different letters in amsrefs?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, amsrefs

It seems that [amsrefs strikes again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50027/how-to-change-the-appeareance-of-bibliography-item-labels-in-amsrefs)!  I'd like to have more than one bibliography, and in the first one, the entries should be marked, say, as [A1], [A2] etc., in the second, say, [B1], [B2] etc. and so on.  I could use `\BibLabel` to modify the look of the entries in the bibliography, and modify `\cite@somethings` to modify the references, but this seems to be an ugly hack.  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, nobody took the challenge;), so I had to dig through some `amsrefs` code myself.  (Not that I understand it completely - it seems to be rather a mess...)  This code did the trick:

```
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setbibprefix}[1]{\def\bib@prefix{#1}}
\pretocmd{\thebib}{\bib@prefix}{}{}
\setbibprefix{}
\makeatother
```